# web3 eth.sign error: invalid address

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am getting an error when trying to sign data with web3 and metamask

`signed_data = myWeb3.eth.sign("hello", web3.eth.accounts[0])`

web3.eth.accounts[0] is populated with my account number in string form

Results in error:

`Uncaught Error: invalid address
    at c (inpage.js:1)
    at inpage.js:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at o.formatInput (inpage.js:1)
    at o.toPayload (inpage.js:1)
    at n.e [as sign] (inpage.js:1)
    at test.html:12`

Answer (score 4):

Take a look here at a complete working sample of signing and recovering messages with Web3.js and MetaMask:

https://github.com/shawntabrizi/web3js-sign-and-verify-ethereum

You can play around with a deployed version of this code here:

https://shawntabrizi.com/ethsign/

There could be a few problems here with your code, which is hard to decipher with the information you provided:

- Using `web3.eth.sign` vs `web3.eth.personal.sign`. Starting with Web3.js 1.0, using `personal` where possible is much better, and this is what should be used for MetaMask accounts
- `web3.eth.accounts[0]` not being populated. In Web3.js 1.0, this value is not populated by default. Instead you need to get accounts using something like:

  ```
  var accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  console.log(accounts[0])
  ```
- Order of your parameters. Depending on the version of Web3.js you are using, the order of the parameters change:

  ```
  web3.eth.sign(address, dataToSign [, callback]) // web3.js 0.x.x

  web3.eth.sign(dataToSign, address [, callback]) // web3.js 1.0
  ```

Given the number of issues, it would be best you start with a working sample like the one I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your web3.eth.sign call as:-`web3.eth.sign(address, dataToSign, [, callback]);`
You just passing wrong order of argument to sign() function. May this will help you out.

Comment: i have tried it both ways and get the same error